# Give child class based on parent class only on target container

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to give an element (.item) a class based on a childclass - but I want to keep it to the target container. Below you can see the script im trying - this give all of my elements with the class .left an extra class based on the .item class. I only want this to happen to the container that actually have this class. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><!-- give class -->
    <div class="item itemonlypicture"> </div>
    <div class="left"> </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item"> </div>
    <div class="left"> </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item "> </div>
    <div class="left"> </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($(".item").hasClass("itemonlypicture")) {
        $(".container").addClass("image");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try updated solution and let me know if still it is not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `closest` to get the first ancestor matching the passed selector.

```
$('.itemonlypicture').closest('.container').addClass('myClass');
```

```js
$('.itemonlypicture').closest('.container').addClass('myClass');
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item itemonlypicture">1</div>
  <div class="left">2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="left">4</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="item ">5</div>
  <div class="left">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question - i want to give the parent a class based on the child. updated my question now.

Comment: This kinda works - It gives the element above my target element a class - But in my live html the "parent" element is one step above - can i target a specific element inside my container instead of using .parent?

Comment: Jesus that was easy.. I feel stupid now-- Not just because I made it unnecessary hard by asking the question bad. Wow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below JS

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("itemonlypicture"))
    {
      $(this).closest(".container").addClass("image");
    }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="container">
<div>  <--- give class
   <div class="item itemonlypicture"> </div>
   <div class="left"> </div>     
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="container">   
   <div class="item"> </div>
   <div class="left"> </div>     
  </div>


 <div class="container"> 
   <div class="item "> </div>
   <div class="left"> </div>     
  </div>
```

Comment: I mixed up my code - I want to give my .container class the extra class based on the child - but only on the specific container that have that child. sorry for this, updated my question.

Comment: np check now I also updated my answer as per your question :)

Comment: @Xeptor this answer is not working or any other issue?

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work - It doesnt generate an error - but my element doesn't get a class.

Comment: @Xeptor But I can check here and it is updating class on correct div, I think you have some other issue can you please paste your complete HTML and JS you are trying?

Comment: My live code has another element before my .container element - thus not being a parent. It worked when I tried it on the direct parent - i need to target one element above, still in my main container but not a parent. clumpsy asked question by me - will update.

Comment: @Xeptor try now I think this time it should work otherwise please paste your HTML here we will update it